# Maven and Embedded Glassfish Plugin - How to provide the derby jdbc driver

Tags: maven, client, driver, javadb, glassfish-embedded

When running the embedded glassfish plugin I get the following message.

```
INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available by default.
```

How to provide the javadb client jar file?